# How to set bindings in ngFor in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

**NOTE**: I found several similar questions but none really answered my (generic) question

I have this

**component.ts**

```
first: string;
second: string;
third: string;
fields = ["first", "second", "third"];
```

I want to be able to generate in **component.html** a complex component (**without importing a custom-defined directive**) which includes:

- **Required**: ngModel binding based on fields[i]

  (e.g. i = 0, fields[i] = "first", ngModel = **first**)
- **Desiderable**: use fields[i] as strings to assign to any DOM element property (e.g.

The loop looks like this:

```
 <div *ngFor="let field of fields">
      <label for="???>
      [(ngModel)]="???"
 </div>
```

As for the 2nd point, it works with id and as content of the div.

However...

- in the case of ngModel: [(ngModel)] = "field" leads to an exception (**Cannot assign to a reference or variable!**)
- in the case of assigning a string to (for example)

  ```
   <label for="{{field}}">,
  ```

  I get an exception as well (**Can't bind to 'for' since it isn't a known native property (" i">**)

Comment: For the first part, have you tried a one-way binding with `[for]="field"`?

Comment: that works for RC6 (that I can't test for now) according to Gunter answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**>=RC.6**

```
 <label for="{{field}}">
 <label [for]="field">
```

**<=RC.5**

```
 <label attr.for="{{field}}">
 <label [attr.for]="field">
 <label [htmlFor]="field">
```

**update**

```
<div *ngFor="let field of fields; let i=index; trackBy:trackByIndex">
  <label htmlFor="field">
  <input [(ngModel)]="fields[i]">
</div>
```

and add this to the component

```
trackByIndex(index: number, obj: any): any {
  return index;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Gunter. but this doesn't answer my main question (about ngModel)

Comment: I updated my answer. If you get an error please post the exact error message.

Comment: Gunter, the example is: take the current element from ngFor (let element of elements). element is a string (there is an example in my question). I want to assign that string to [(ngModel)] as it was the name of a property of the "controller" (in the .ts file I would use this["string"]). Is it clearer?

Comment: I tried with index. it in fact works. but multiple elements (the generated divs) take the same NgModel (when I update one <input [(ngModel)]=... all the others do, even though field is always different (in the loop)

Comment: I see. That's an issue with primitive values. I updated my answer. You don't need this `trackBy` stuff if the items in `fields` are objects.

Comment: I can't test it now but assuming it works, I'll accept the answer when I catch up on this ;)

Comment: Im confused, is your ngModel attribute not attached to any tag? Does this mean something special or a typo?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just copied the code from the question and missed that mistake.

Comment: I'm trying your updated answer but I'm losing focus on every keypress in the input field.

Comment: You mean with `trackBy`? Can you create a Plunker that demonstrates the issue?