# How to solve checkbox modifying other checkboxes state (not the model)?

Tags: angular, checkbox

I have a `for` that goes over elements in a array of Boolean variables and uses each Boolean as a model for a checkbox.

The `models` array looks like this:

```
  models = [true,false,true,true,false,false,true];
```

The template looks like this:

```
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1><br>
<div *ngFor="let mod of models; let i=index">
    <input [(ngModel)]="models[i]" type="checkbox">
</div>
<pre>{{models|json}}</pre>
```

When I click a checkbox, a random element changes its state too.
Not sure if this is a bug or I'm just not understanding something.

How do I make this checkboxes behave appropriately?

Complete example showing this behavior: https://plnkr.co/edit/siTXHoIF3OuXnZd37yir?p=preview

Comment: You need to refer to this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347773/how-to-set-bindings-in-ngfor-in-angular-2

Comment: See plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/fXPfLTnotRgX2cm1jGyB?p=preview

Comment: @wannadream You have found the solution I was looking for. Would you please post an answer so I can accept it? (PS: could you add <pre>{{models|json}}</pre> to your plunker so the UI looks the same to mine and people spot the difference more easily?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my edited plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/fXPfLTnotRgX2cm1jGyB?p=preview

Basically, you need to track object in ngFor: [How to set bindings in ngFor in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347773/how-to-set-bindings-in-ngfor-in-angular-2)

In template:

```
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1><br>
<div *ngFor="let mod of models; let i=index,trackBy:trackByIndex">
    <input [(ngModel)]="models[i]" type="checkbox" (click)="onClick(i)">
</div>
<pre>{{models}}</pre>
```

In component.ts:

```
  trackByIndex(index: number, obj: any): any {
    return index;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code to use an array of objects as the model instead of an array of plain booleans. That's seems a bit more idiomatic to me, and it fixes your problem.

With this approach too you could add stuff like a `label` field and other information to the model for each checkbox, and use that in your template, so in general I think this is a better way of handling things.

There's probably a better way of approaching this using Angular 2, but I'm really not familiar with it myself, sorry.

https://plnkr.co/edit/8561HPbx7hDcHsTVq1C4?p=preview

```
models = [
      {
        selected : true
      },
      {
        selected : false
      },
      {
        selected : true
      },
      {
        selected : true
      },
      {
        selected : false
      },
      {
        selected : false
      },
      {
        selected : true
      },
  ];
```